# Script to record the sound of a program to the microphone

Tags: shell, audio, pulseaudio

I want to make a shell script to record the sound of a program and to direct it as an microphone entry on linux.

For instance, I'm listening a music on youtube, and I want that music to be send to my skype's conversation instead of my voice.

Last but not least, I know how to do it using pavucontrol, I have to go to "Recording" and to switch the "Record stream from", but I want to do the exact same thing from the command line, and not using a gui.

I tried this:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback source=1 sink=2
```

(where 1 is my desktop sound, 2 is Analog Stereo Duplex (but it also includes the normal sound on top of my input....) and it doesn't work as expected. I don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: also asked here: http://superuser.com/q/655449/4714

Comment: I'm maximizing my chances of getting an answer, because my question is compatible with those two sites. I Also asked on Ubuntu forums, and pulseaudio IRC. No answer. Thanks for your constructive comment.

Comment: I'm not chastizing you. I'm alerting readers of the question that they may want to look for answers on the other site.

Comment: okay, thanks then, saw your comment in a confused way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`module-loopback` can only be used to short-circuit sources to sinks. (i.e. mic to speaker.) The switch you found in pavucontrol can be accessed from the command line via

```
 pactl move-source-output <source output> <source>
```

You can get the source output ID via

```
pactl list source-outputs
```

while a program is recording, and a list of sources using

```
pactl list sources
```

You can also supply the source by name, e.g. `combined.monitor`.

I just tried it with mplayer and audacity and noticed two pitfalls:

- If the monitor is stereo and your default source is mono, applications might not
  like being rerouted. You can use
  [module-remap-source](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules)
  to work around that: Remap the monitor to one mono channel and move the source output to 
  the newly created remapped source.
- You might need to unmute the monitor device in pavucontrol before this works. From the 
  command line this can be done using `pactl set-source-mute`. (See `man pactl`)

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks you very much, I was seeking for this answer for a decade now :) !

Comment: @sidney I've seen people use [Jack](http://www.jackaudio.org/) for mixing / rerouting audio; cf., e.g., [this](http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/routing_alsa.html) or [this](http://alien.slackbook.org/blog/setting-up-jack-audio-in-slackware/).